# Unit testing DataContext on Windows 8 Phone

Tags: c#, windows, unit-testing, windows-phone-8

How do I unit test DataContext on windows 8 phone?

I have something like the following:

```
 [Database]
    class MyDataContext : DataContext
    {
        private static readonly string db_string = "Data Source=isostore:/MyDatabase.sdf";

        public MobileAnalyticsDataContext()
            : base(db_string)
        { }

        public Table<Foo> Foo;

    }
```

I am trying to unit test MyDataContext on **Windows 8 Phone unit test.**

When I try to create a table and insert data into Foo, I get System.UnauthorizedException.

When I try running the test method, it opens up the emulator and I guess the test code runs on the emulator.

How do I get around the problem? Is there a way to grant permission to the ISO data source for running tests?

Comment: Here I moved to comment up here instead. Didn't realize Fakes was only for VS 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: I thought I could just go grab a test framework (for mocking) for Windows 8 phone from NuGet. Now I am leaning towards writing a mock implementation myself and inject it into the class.

Comment: Yeah I would add some more interfaces and go that route. 

On a side not I found this that works in .NET 4.5. It's not mocking but it makes setting up your expected outcomes for your test easier.

http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: I don't know much about Win 8 phone or .NET. Just started developing a client library in the past 2 weeks. I believe win 8 phone uses .NET 4.5. What is interesting was that whatever I tried were not compatible with either 4.5 or with VS Express for Windows 8 phone. I could be wrong as I am not educated enough to comment on .Net or Win 8.

Comment: Some third party libraries take a little time to adjust their frameworks to meet the new versions of .NET.

Comment: Windows Phone doesnt have reflection capabilities for any mocking framework to Work.